# Is Zork and the arcade zombies the only thing the terminal gives access to in Black Ops?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops

I know from breaking free in the chair in Black Ops, you can access the arcade Zombies with `doa` and Zork with `zork`.

Are there any others?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While there aren't specifically any more games available from the console, there's quite a lot of things that can be done with the console.

Some of the highlights would be unlocking one of the Zombie maps, Five, by typing in `3arc unlock`, or you can try the virtual therapist `alicia`. You can login to user accounts, open files and do some other things.

The most complete list of commands that I've seen is found at the [Call of Duty Wiki](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Central_Intelligence_Agency_Data_system)

Comment: thx for the cheat code. I'll try that at home.

Answer (score 0):

There is lots to be discovered by logging into other systems with rlogin commands.
I think no one has been able to crack the passwords for derriese server accounts like samantha, drmaxis etc.

Comment: Lots of things like what? This is far too vague.